# Will changing class make any difference when importing a character?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Will importing a Mass Effect 2 character and changing class (e.g. ME2:Soldier -> ME3:Engineer) make any difference?  Will it be without any penalties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is it makes no difference if you change class. When you land on Mars you start with a clean ability slate and can spend your imported ability points on whichever skills your want.